# How to fill in a cell with text based on a value

Tags: excel

I want to fill in one cell with text based on another cell that has a number. So for example if A1 reads 2 I want B1 to read Correct.

In my case I have multiple possible criteria, B1 = Correct is just ONE example.

Will this be a conditional format formula involving an IF function or vlookup possibly?

Basically what I'm looking to do is IF A1 = 2, than B1 = Text

Thanks in advance for an answer to this

Comment: Kinda hoping you or someone would know of a formula....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a VLOOKUP formula
to do this you need a table of key and value
for example
in the range d1:E6 you have the lookup table.

```
Lookup  LookupValue
1   May be correct
2   Don't know
3   It depends
4   probably correct
5   My wife says it is correct
```

In the range a1:c7 you have your data

```
col1    col2    col3
kjkjk   2   Don't know
klkl    2   Don't know
jkljkjk 1   May be correct
kjukjkjk    4   probably correct
lklklkl 5   My wife says it is correct 
lklklkl 3   It depends
```

in col3 you use the VLOOKUP
as =VLOOKUP(B2, MyLookupTable, 2)

Note that I named the d1:e6 range as MyLookupTable[image]

THis is what it looks like

[image]